# Create a dataframe from the model

Tags: python, django, pandas, dataframe, model

I am writing an application using Django and I ran into a problem. I have models that are as follows:

```
class Feature(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    feature_name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    feature_code = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    feature_predictable = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.feature_name


def breed_name_based_upload_to(instance, filename):
    return "breeds/{0}/{1}".format(instance.breed_name, filename)


class Breed(models.Model):
    breed_name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    breed_features = models.ManyToManyField(Feature)
    breed_image = models.ImageField(default='no_image.png', upload_to=breed_name_based_upload_to)
    breed_visible = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.breed_name


class FeatureValue(models.Model):
    breed = models.ForeignKey(Breed, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    feature = models.ForeignKey(Feature, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    feature_value = IntegerRangeField(min_value=1, max_value=3, default=1)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('breed', 'feature')
```

In the 'Feature' model, I have 3 records with feature_code with values for example 'value1', 'value2', 'value3'. In the 'Breed' model I also have 3 records, with each of these records assigned values for each record from the 'Feature' model (I use the FeatureValue model for assigning values).

Now I need to use the Breed model to create a DataFrame that would look like this:

```
id   breed_name  value1   value2   value3
 0        name1       2        1        3
 1        name2       1        2        2
 2        name3       3        3        3
```

At the moment, using this code:

```
dataframe = pandas.DataFrame().from_records(list(
    Breed.objects.all().values(
        'id',
        'breed_name',
        'featurevalue__feature_value'
    )
))
```

I managed to achieve something like this:

```
id   breed_name   featurevalue__feature_value
 0        name1                             2
 0        name1                             1
 0        name1                             3
 1        name2                             1
 1        name2                             2
 1        name2                             2
 2        name3                             3
 2        name3                             3
 2        name3                             3
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we start from your example dataframe.

You can enumerate rows in each group of `breed_name` values.

```
>>> df["pos"] = df.groupby("breed_name").cumcount()
>>> df["pos"] = "value" + df["pos"].astype("str")
>>> df
   id breed_name  featurevalue__feature_value     pos
0   0      name1                            2  value0
1   0      name1                            1  value1
2   0      name1                            3  value2
3   1      name2                            1  value0
4   1      name2                            2  value1
5   1      name2                            2  value2
6   2      name3                            3  value0
7   2      name3                            3  value1
8   2      name3                            3  value2
```

Then pivot the dataframe, delete extra level of columns index and reset row index.

```
>>> df2 = df.pivot(columns="pos", index=["id", "breed_name"])
>>> df2
              featurevalue__feature_value
pos                                value0 value1 value2
id breed_name
0  name1                                2      1      3
1  name2                                1      2      2
2  name3                                3      3      3

>>> df2 = df2.droplevel(0, axis=1).reset_index()
>>> df2
pos  id breed_name  value0  value1  value2
0     0      name1       2       1       3
1     1      name2       1       2       2
2     2      name3       3       3       3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as below:

```
df2 = df.groupby(['id','breed_name'], as_index=False).agg(list)

max_values = df2.featurevalue__feature_value.str.len().max()
df2[['value'+str(i+1) for i in range(max_values)]] = df2.featurevalue__feature_value.apply(pd.Series)

df2.drop('featurevalue__feature_value', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

###### Output:

```
>>> df2
   id breed_name  value1  value2  value3
0   0      name1       2       1       3
1   1      name2       1       2       2
2   2      name3       3       3       3
```

##### Explanation:

1. First [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) **id, breed_name** columns and aggregate the result as `list`.
2. Then find `max` no. of **value** columns needed, and convert the aggregated list values in
   **featurevalue__feature_value** column to seperate **value** columns using [`pandas.Series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.html).
3. Finally drop the **featurevalue__feature_value** column.